# scala - Any vs underscore in generics

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, any, existential-type

What is the different between the following Generics definitions in Scala:

```
class Foo[T <: List[_]]
```

and

```
class Bar[T <: List[Any]]
```

My gut tells me they are about the same but that the latter is more explicit. I am finding cases where the former compiles but the latter doesn't, but can't put my finger on the exact difference.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Can I throw another into the mix?

```
class Baz[T <: List[_ <: Any]]
```

Comment: Constraining a type to be `<: Any` never changes anything. Every type in Scala is `<: Any`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

OK, I figured I should have my take on it, instead of just posting comments. Sorry, this is going to be long, if you want the TL;DR skip to the end.

As Randall Schulz said, here `_` is a shorthand for an existential type. Namely,

```
class Foo[T <: List[_]]
```

is a shorthand for

```
class Foo[T <: List[Z] forSome { type Z }]
```

Note that contrary to what Randall Shulz's answer mentions (full disclosure: I got it wrong too in an earlier version of this post, thanks to Jesper Nordenberg for pointing it out) this not the same as:

```
class Foo[T <: List[Z]] forSome { type Z }
```

nor is it the same as:

```
class Foo[T <: List[Z forSome { type Z }]]
```

Beware, it is easy to get it wrong (as my earlier goof shows): the author of the article referenced by Randall Shulz's answer got it wrong himself (see comments), and fixed it later. My main problem with this article is that in the example shown, the use of existentials is supposed to save us from a typing problem, but it does not. Go check the code, and try to compile `compileAndRun(helloWorldVM("Test"))` or `compileAndRun(intVM(42))`. Yep, does not compile. Simply making `compileAndRun` generic in `A` would make the code compile, and it would be much simpler.
In short, that's probably not the best article to learn about existentials and what they are good for (the author himself acknowledge in a comment that the article "needs tidying up").

So I would rather recommend reading this article: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scalas_type_system.html, in particular the sections named "Existential types" and "Variance in Java and Scala".

The important point that you hould get from this article is that existentials are useful (apart from being able to deal with generic java classes) when dealing with non-covariant types.
Here is an example.

```
case class Greets[T]( private val name: T ) {
  def hello() { println("Hello " + name) }
  def getName: T = name
}
```

This class is generic (note also that is is invariant), but we can see that `hello` really doesn't make any use of the type parameter (unlike `getName`), so if I get an instance of `Greets` I should always be able to call it, whatever `T` is.  If I want to define a method that takes a `Greets` instance and just calls its `hello` method, I could try this:

```
def sayHi1( g: Greets[T] ) { g.hello() } // Does not compile
```

Sure enough, this does not compile, as `T` comes out of nowhere here.

OK then, let's make the method generic:

```
def sayHi2[T]( g: Greets[T] ) { g.hello() }
sayHi2( Greets("John"))
sayHi2( Greets('Jack))
```

Great, this works. We could also use existentials here:

```
def sayHi3( g: Greets[_] ) { g.hello() }
sayHi3( Greets("John"))
sayHi3( Greets('Jack))
```

Works too. So all in all, there is no real benefit here from using an existential (as in `sayHi3`) over type parameter (as in `sayHi2`).

However, this changes if `Greets` appears itself as a type parameter to another generic class. Say by example that we want to store several instances of `Greets` (with different `T`) in a list. Let's try it:

```
val greets1: Greets[String] = Greets("John")
val greets2: Greets[Symbol] = Greets('Jack)
val greetsList1: List[Greets[Any]] = List( greets1, greets2 ) // Does not compile
```

The last line does not compile because `Greets` is invariant, so a `Greets[String]` and `Greets[Symbol]` cannot be treated as a `Greets[Any]` even though `String` and `Symbol` both extends `Any`.

OK, let's try with an existential, using the shorthand notation `_`:

```
val greetsList2: List[Greets[_]] = List( greets1, greets2 ) // Compiles fine, yeah
```

This compiles fine, and you can do, as expected:

```
greetsSet foreach (_.hello)
```

Now, remember that the reason we had a type checking problem in the first place was because `Greets` is invariant. If it was turned into a covariant class (`class Greets[+T]`) then everything would have worked out of the box and we would never have needed existentials.

---

So to sum up, existentials are useful to deal with generic invariant classes, but if the generic class does not need to appear itself as a type parameter to another generic class, chances are that you don't need existentials and simply adding a type parameter to your method will work

Now come back(at last, I know!) to your specific question, regarding

```
class Foo[T <: List[_]]
```

Because `List` is covariant, this is for all intents and purpose the same as just saying:

```
class Foo[T <: List[Any]]
```

So in this case, using either notation is really just a matter of style.

However, if you replace `List` with `Set`, things change:

```
class Foo[T <: Set[_]]
```

`Set` is invariant and thus we are in the same situation as with the `Greets` class from my example. Thus the above really is very different from

```
class Foo[T <: Set[Any]]
```

Comment: No, `class Foo[T <: List[_]]` is shorthand for `class Foo[T <: List[Z] forSome { type Z }]`. The same way `List[Greets[_]]` is shorthand for `List[Greets[Z] forSome { type Z }]` (and not `List[Greets[Z]] forSome { type Z }`).

Comment: Doh, silly me! Thanks, I've fixed this. Funny enough, my first though was to check the article by David R MacIver (http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) that precisely talks about  the existentials shorthand, and warns about their unintuitive desugaring. The thing is he appears to have it wrong himself. Actually, what happened is that the way the desugaring is done changed shortly after his article (in scala 2.7.1, see change log at http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43#2.8.0). I guess this change participates to the confusion.

Comment: Well, it's easy to mix up the meaning of the existential type syntax. At least the current desugaring is the most logical IMHO.

Comment: where does the last `]` go in `class Foo[T <: List[Z forSome { type Z }]`?

Comment: Yes indeed, there was a missing `]` at the end. That should have been `class Foo[T <: List[Z forSome { type Z }]]`. Fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The former is a shorthand for an existential type when the code doesn't need to know what the type is or constrain it:

```
class Foo[T <: List[Z forSome { type Z }]]
```

This form says that the element type of `List` is unknown to `class Foo` rather than your second form, which says specifically that the `List`'s element type is `Any`.

Check out this brief explanatory [blog article](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/09/03/existential-types/) on Existential Types in Scala (**EDIT**: this link is now dead, a snapshot is available at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170901215553/http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/09/03/existential-types/))

Comment: While you explain what an existential is, I think the question is not what existentials are in general, but is there any actual observable difference between `T[_]` (which is particular case of existential use) and `T[Any]`?

Comment: Of course there is. The blog I referred to has a nice illustration of it.

Comment: I'd rather have **your** answer mention how covariance is essential to the difference between `T[_]` and `T[Any]`, as it is at the heart of the question "why even use `T[_] ` over `T[Any]`". In addition, in his question Sean Connolly explicitly mentioned `List[_]`. Given that `List` is actually covariant, one can wonder if **in this case** there really is a difference between `List[_]` and `List[Any]`.

Comment: If T is covariant **and** its type parameter has `Any` as its upper bound, then there doesn't seem to be any difference between `T[_]` and `T[Any]`. However, if you have `T[+A <: B]` the compiler oddly enough can't infer `T[_ <: B]` from `T[_]`.

Comment: @Jesper Nordenberg: Actually in scala pre-2.8 this inference worked, it got "broken" in scala 2.8. In fact, it was on purpose because apparently this played badly with the rest of type system, and was inconsistent (I cannot remember the details though).

Comment: is there a `]` missing here?

Comment: Yes indeed, there was a missing `]` at the end, fixed now.