# Understanding scala's _ vs Any/Nothing

Tags: scala, wildcard, covariance, contravariance, type-systems

If a class has a convariant type parameter such as [`Iterable[+A]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs-2.10.1/library/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable), is there any difference between declaring

```
def foo(bar: Iterable[_])
```

and

```
def foo(bar: Iterable[Any])
```

?

---

If a class has a contravariant type parameter such as [`Growable[-A]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs-2.10.1/library/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Growable), is there any difference between declaring

```
def foo(bar: Growable[_])
```

and

```
def foo(bar: Growable[Nothing])
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala - Any vs underscore in generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186520/scala-any-vs-underscore-in-generics)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but close enough. I'll let others judge.

Answer (score 5):

It does make a little difference when generic parameter is bounded. For example, if you had

```
class BoundedIterable[+A <: Something]
class BoundedGrowable[-A >: Something]
```

then type `BoundedIterable[Any]` and `BoundedGrowable[Nothing]` would be illegal.

I don't know if there is any other difference, but I can say for sure that you should prefer the wildcard-less variant wherever possible. That is because, actually, the very purpose of declaration-site type variance is to get rid of wildcards (which are a form of usage-site variance). When you say `List[Any]` you mean "list of anything", but when you say `List[_]` then you mean "list of we-don't-know-what". So the former is just way more clear, even though they may be equivalent in some particular case.

Comment: If a type parameter is bounded by `Something`, we could simply use `Something` in the place of `Any`/`Nothing`. In such a case, we could write `def foo(bar: MyBoundedType[Something])` (for both the covariant and contravariant case).

Comment: @Peter That's true. That's why I called it "a little" difference :)