# Return Generic Polymorphic Return Type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

In an example below, I like to return any type of `Container` from the function `getInfos` and from the caller side to perform map with pattern matching however I get compiler error that I cannot return `Container[_]`. Is there a way to return `Container` of any type? If not, what is the best way to approach this?

```
  trait Info[T] {
    def value: T
  }

  case class ContainerAInfo(value: Long) extends Info[Long]
  case class ContainerBInfo(value: String, value2: String) extends Info[String]
  
  trait Container[T] {
    def info: Info[T]
  }
  
  case class ContainerA[Long](projectionInfo: ContainerAInfo)
  case class ContainerB[String](projectionInfo: ContainerBInfo)

  def getInfos: Seq[Container[_]] = {
    Seq(
      ContainerA(
        projectionInfo = ContainerAInfo(1L)
      ),
      ContainerB(
        projectionInfo = ContainerBInfo("12", "12")
      )
    )

  }
```

Comment: You may make it covariant and return `Seq[Container[Any]]`, you may use type members rather than type parameters, or you may just make it a regular ADT and remove the generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Long` and `String` in

```
case class ContainerA[Long](...)
case class ContainerB[String](...)
```

are not standard `Long` (`scala.Long`) and `String` (`scala.Predef.String` aka `java.lang.String`). You introduce new generics shadowing standard `Long` and `String`. It's better to switch on `scalacOptions += "-Xlint:type-parameter-shadow"` to avoid such confusion

[Type Arguments and Bounds in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725562/type-arguments-and-bounds-in-scala)

[What causes this type error in a pattern guard for matching list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443888/what-causes-this-type-error-in-a-pattern-guard-for-matching-list-of-tuples)

[Strange Error with String in Scala 2.12.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598220/strange-error-with-string-in-scala-2-12-7)

[Type parameters applied to Scala Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718070/type-parameters-applied-to-scala-function)

I suspect `ContainerA` and `ContainerB` are supposed to extend `Container`, don't they? So a minimal change to your code making it compile is

```
case class ContainerA(info: ContainerAInfo) extends Container[Long]
case class ContainerB(info: ContainerBInfo) extends Container[String]

def getInfos: Seq[Container[_]] = {
  Seq(
    ContainerA(
      info = ContainerAInfo(1L)
    ),
    ContainerB(
      info = ContainerBInfo("12", "12")
    )
  )

}
```

`Container[_]` is an existential type, a minimal supertype of all `Container[T]`, including `Container[Long]`, `Container[String]`, `Container[Any]`

[scala - Any vs underscore in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186520/scala-any-vs-underscore-in-generics)

[Understanding scala's _ vs Any/Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310329/understanding-scalas-vs-any-nothing)

[What is an existential type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292274/what-is-an-existential-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider making the hierarchy covariant and using `Seq[Container[Any]]`:

```scala
trait Info [+T] {
  def value: T
}

case class ContainerAInfo (value: Long) extends Info [Long]
case class ContainerBInfo (value: String, value2: String) extends Info [String]

trait Container [+T] {
  def projectionInfo: Info [T]
}

case class ContainerA (projectionInfo: ContainerAInfo) extends Container [Long]
case class ContainerB (projectionInfo: ContainerBInfo) extends Container [String]

def getInfos: Seq [Container [Any]] =
  Seq (
    ContainerA (
      projectionInfo = ContainerAInfo (1L)
    ), ContainerB (
      projectionInfo = ContainerBInfo ("12", "12")
    )
  )
```

Though possibly it will not be that useful.

[Demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/z5WaM7qESbiO9zDBbnypdw)