# Type alias parameter bounds not enforced in all cases

Tags: scala, generics, types, case-class

TL;DR: It appears that type parameters of type aliases (e.g. `type T[X<:Serializable]`) do not enforce their constraints when referenced as variables, parameters and perhaps other cases. Case classes, however, do enforce the bounds correctly for their parameters.

Consider a type alias designed to represent a subset of generic type. For example, let us say I want a type for lists of `Serializable` things:

```
scala> type SerializableList[T <: Serializable] = List[T]
defined type alias SerializableList
```

Now say that I want a case class with a parameter of these things:

```
scala> case class NetworkDataCC(things: SerializableList[_])
<console>:9: error: type arguments [_$1] do not conform to type SerializableList's type parameter bounds [T <: Serializable]
   case class NetworkDataCC(things: SerializableList[_])
```

Well, that doesn't work. Scala (annoyingly) does not carry the parameter bounds with the type, but it's easy to fix:

```
scala> case class NetworkDataCC(things: SerializableList[_ <: Serializable])
defined class NetworkDataCC
```

Alright. Looks good. Now, what if I want just a regular class with those things, but I again forget to explicitly declare the type bounds. I expect an error:

```
scala> class NetworkData(val things: SerializableList[_])
defined class NetworkData
```

Oh, wait. No error... huh.

So, now I can do this?

```
scala> new NetworkData(List(1))
res3: NetworkData = NetworkData@e344ad3
```

Well, that seems quite broken. The case class, works fine of course (because the restrictions were declared):

```
scala> NetworkDataCC(List(1))
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Serializable
              NetworkDataCC(List(1))
```

In my project, I am making use of reflection to generate some metadata about my classes. The metadata for the non-case-class shows a lack of bounds on `things`:

```
scala> classOf[NetworkData].getDeclaredFields()(0).getGenericType
res0: java.lang.reflect.Type = scala.collection.immutable.List<?>
```

Whereas the case class is correct:

```
scala> classOf[NetworkDataCC].getDeclaredFields()(0).getGenericType
res1: java.lang.reflect.Type = scala.collection.immutable.List<? extends scala.Serializable>
```

I wasn't able to find any bugs in the scala compiler bug tracker for this. Am I misunderstanding how these bounds should be used?

Comment: Interesting question. I suspect the compiler to choke on the `unapply`-method created by the case class. I wonder why the non-case class compiles though. But the problem seems to manifest even if we are not declaring a new class. The compiler happlily accepts `val y: SerializableList[_] = List(1)` which should already be an invalid expression. Maybe the type alias causes the problem?

Comment: Addendum (non-case class) to my previous comment: The function `def unapply(value: NetworkDataCC): Option[SerializableList[_]] = Some(value.things)` does not compile, printing the error: `type arguments [_$1] do not conform to type SerializableList's type parameter bounds [T <: Serializable]`. However, the compiler does accept `def unapply(value: NetworkDataCC): Option[SerializableList[_]] = Some(value.things.asInstanceOf[SerializableList[Serializable]])` which also matches `NetworkDataCC(List(1))` at runtime, returning `List(1)`.

Comment: I'm quite interested in this one. I started a bounty on it, hopefully someone can answer.

Answer (score 4):

Scala's underscore is not equivalent to `SerializableList[X forSome {type X}]` by default:

```
scala> def aa(a: SerializableList[_]) = a
aa: (a: SerializableList[_])List[Any]

scala> def aa(a: SerializableList[X forSome {type X}]) = a
<console>:11: error: type arguments [X forSome { type X }] do not conform to type SerializableList's type parameter bounds [T <: Serializable]
   def aa(a: SerializableList[X forSome {type X}]) = a
             ^
scala> class NetworkDataCC(things: SerializableList[X forSome {type X}])
<console>:11: error: type arguments [X forSome { type X }] do not conform to typ
e SerializableList's type parameter bounds [T <: Serializable]
   class NetworkDataCC(things: SerializableList[X forSome {type X}])
```

It is equivalent to

```
scala> def aa(a: SerializableList[X] forSome {type X} ) = a
aa: (a: SerializableList[_])List[Any]
```

So such "unbounded" behavior is fine. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15204140/1809978

Case classes seem to have additional type restrictions (due to [this bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1786), which affects `unapply` method, automatically generated for case class).

If you want to have "unbounded" existential type in case class, just specify higher-order type explicitly:

```
 scala> case class NetworkDataCC[SerializableList[_]](things: SerializableList[_])
 warning: there were 2 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
 defined class NetworkDataCC

 scala> NetworkDataCC(List(1))
 res5: NetworkDataCC[List] = NetworkDataCC(List(1))
```

Or even:

```
 scala> type SLL = SerializableList[_]
 defined type alias SLL

 scala> case class NetworkDataDD(things: SLL)
 defined class NetworkDataDD
```

So this is definitely a bug regarding that you can workaround it with semantically equivalent type alias (see [SI-8997](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8997))