# Function argument of Traversable foldLeft results in type mismatch

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a function that operates with traversable object.

```
def f[V, M[_] <: Traversable[_]](ei: M[V])(builder: GenericCompanion[M]): M[V] =
  ei.foldLeft(builder.empty[V])((accum: M[V], el: V) => builder(el))
```

This code doesn't compile because of

```
Error:(22, 57) type mismatch;
 found   : el.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: V
  ei.foldLeft(builder.empty[V])((accum, el) => builder(el))
                                                       ^
```

Reproduced with scala 2.11.8 and 2.12.1. It's bizarre. Why `el` is assumed as `Any`?

---

I could solve it with cats library. So question is not 'How to do it?' but 'Why pure scala code is wrong?'.

```
def f[V, M[_] : Foldable : Alternative](ei: M[V]): M[V] = {
  val monoidK = implicitly[MonoidK[M]]

  ei.foldLeft(monoidK.empty[V]) {
    (accum, el) => monoidK.algebra[V].combine(accum, el.pure[M])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem with `_` in type bounds, after replacing it with a letter `X` it compiles.

```
def f[V, M[X] <: Traversable[X]](ei: M[V])(builder: GenericCompanion[M]): M[V] =
  ei.foldLeft(builder.empty[V])((accum: M[V], el: V) => builder(el))
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15204140/187261) for some intuition. As I understand

`M[_] <: Traversable[_]` is `M` that extends `Traversable[Any]` and has some type hole. In other words it fills type hole in `Traversable` with `Any` and then creates a new type hole in `M` (that you don't need).

`M[X] <: Traversable[X]` synchronizes type holes in `M` and `Traversable`. So whatever type is put in `M` it will be placed in `Traversable`

Comment: Thanks! I missed type variable binding.