# Understanding type arguments do not conform to class type parameter bounds error when using Higher kinded type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

I am trying to understand why the following piece of code won't compile when I use a higher kinded type parameter for T in MyModel

```
abstract class Model[M <: Model[M]]

class MyModel[T] extends Model[MyModel[T]]

class Bar[TModel <: Model[TModel]]

object Foo extends App {

  new Bar[MyModel[_]]

}
```

But if i change it to `new Bar[MyModel[Any]]` it will compile. Why is this ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be `Any`, you could make it `new Bar[MyModel[Int]]` and it'll compile. I don't think you can use wildcards when declaring new objects, but I might be wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scala - Any vs underscore in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186520/scala-any-vs-underscore-in-generics)

Comment: @user wildcards can't be used on the first level e.g. `new Some[_](???)` (because `Some[_]` is not a class type) but can be used deeper e.g. `new Some[Option[_]](???)` (because `Some[T]` is a class type and `T=Option[_]` is a type).

Comment: @DmytroMitin That's interesting. Why is `Option[_]` considered a type when it has a wildcard?

Comment: @user because it's an existential type i.e. a type https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types

Comment: @Duelist current question is harder because it's a combination of F-bound and existential type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bar[MyModel[_]]` [is](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#placeholder-syntax-for-existential-types) `Bar[MyModel[X] forSome {type X}]`.

(It should not be confused neither with `Bar[MyModel[X]] forSome {type X}` nor with `Bar[MyModel[X forSome {type X}]]`, the latter [is just](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#simplification-rules) `Bar[MyModel[Any]]`. These are three different types.)

`Bar[MyModel[X] forSome {type X}]` (aka `Bar[MyModel[_]]`) doesn't compile because `MyModel[X] forSome {type X}` (aka `MyModel[_]`) doesn't satisfy `Bar`'s condition `TModel <: Model[TModel]`. Indeed you can check that

```
implicitly[(MyModel[X] forSome {type X}) <:< Model[MyModel[X] forSome {type X}]]
```

doesn't compile (`X` to the left from `<:<` and `X` to the right from `<:<` are not related). [The thing is](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance) that [skolemization](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types) of existential type on the left `MyModel[X] forSome {type X}`, namely `MyModel[X1]` is not connected to `Model[MyModel[X] forSome {type X}]` on the right, for invariant `Model` (from `class MyModel[T] extends Model[MyModel[T]]` it follows that `MyModel[X1] <: Model[MyModel[X1]]` (1), also `MyModel[X1] <: (MyModel[X] forSome {type X})` (2), but for invariant `Model` we can't apply `Model` to the latter "inequality").

But if you make `Model` covariant `abstract class Model[+M <: Model[M]]` then we can apply `Model` to "inequality" (2), so `Model[MyModel[X1]] <: Model[MyModel[X] forSome {type X}]` and this along with (1) gives `MyModel[X1] <: Model[MyModel[X] forSome {type X}]` by transitivity. So `Bar`'s condition is satisfied and `new Bar[MyModel[_]]` compiles.

`Bar[MyModel[Any]]` compiles because `MyModel[Any]` satisfies `Bar`'s condition `TModel <: Model[TModel]`. Indeed `MyModel[Any] <: Model[MyModel[Any]]` because `class MyModel[T] extends Model[MyModel[T]]` (you can check that

```
implicitly[MyModel[Any] <:< Model[MyModel[Any]]]
```

compiles).