# Why can't a polymorphic function accept wildcard (existential) types in Scala?

Tags: scala, existential-type, scala-3, polymorphic-functions

In the example below, I'm wondering why `funPoly` can't accept the existentially quantified type value `outersFromInnersEx`, even though `funEx` can.

```
case class InnerCassClass[I, E, O](i: I, e: E, o: O)
case class OuterCaseClass[I, E, O](inner: InnerCassClass[I, E, O])


val inner1 = InnerCassClass(5, "foo", 3.3f)
val inner2 = InnerCassClass(4.4f, 6, "bar")


// Doesn't work as expected due to invariance of type paramemters I, E, O (but confirm)
// val outersFromInnersAny: List[OuterCaseClass[Any, Any, Any]] = List(inner1, inner2).map(OuterCaseClass.apply)

val outersFromInnersEx: List[OuterCaseClass[_, _, _]] = List(inner1, inner2).map(OuterCaseClass.apply)

def funPoly[I, E, O](occ: List[OuterCaseClass[I, E, O]]): Unit = ()
def funEx(occ: List[OuterCaseClass[_, _, _]]): Unit = ()


// This doesn't work, but why?
val u1 = funPoly(outersFromInnersEx)

val u2 = funEx(outersFromInnersEx)
```

Note, I test this in Scala 3 ([try online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bbarker/z6QEy1KuR12rzAEl97w30Q/18)), but largely the problem is the same in Scala 2, though this particular example has other issues in Scala 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that these two are very different types:

```
def funPoly[I, E, O](occ: List[OuterCaseClass[I, E, O]]): Unit = ()
def funEx(occ: List[OuterCaseClass[_, _, _]]): Unit = ()
```

The first one is able to handle uniform Lists of `OuterCaseClass` objects where the type parameters are the same for every object. The second one can handle mixed Lists of `OuterCaseClass` objects where the type parameters are (potentially) different for every object.

Making the type parameters covariant “fixes” the problem because then `List[OuterCaseClass[_, _, _]]` is equivalent to `List[OuterCaseClass[Any, Any, Any]]`, and you can simply instantiate `funPoly`s type parameters to `Any, Any, Any` to make it accept anything that `funEx` can.

Generally speaking, you can pass existentially qualified types to polymorphic functions. For example, this should work:

```
case class ListAndFunction[A](list: List[A], function: A => Int)
val a: ListAndFunction [_] = ListAndFunction[String](List("a"), _.length)
def mapFunction[A](a: ListAndFunction [A]): List[Int] =
  a.list.map(a.function)
mapFunction(a)
```

Comment: Interesting - I had (apparently incorrectly) assumed that the type system would still be able to compute the underlying type for `outersFromInnersEx` (and according to the type checker, which would have new type parameters that are the intersection of each of the old type parameters (e.g. in my example `I = Float & Int`); at worst I guess this would be `Any`. But it sounds like this isn't quite how the type system works. That aside, your explanation on how covariance works here helped a lot.

Comment: In any event, probably no need for further clarification here, this other SO thread likely paints a good picture, which I'll dive into tomorrow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186520/scala-any-vs-underscore-in-generics

Answer (score 2):

It's about [type variances](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html), you can make `funPoly` work by changing

```
case class InnerCassClass[I, E, O](i: I, e: E, o: O)
case class OuterCaseClass[I, E, O](inner: InnerCassClass[I, E, O])
```

to

```
case class InnerCassClass[+I, +E, +O](i: I, e: E, o: O)
case class OuterCaseClass[+I, +E, +O](inner: InnerCassClass[I, E, O])
```

Comment: Does this somehow imply that functions accepting wildcard types can be unsafe, as they ignore variance? I still don't see the relationship between the variance and existential wildcard types.